# Can't insert records from one table to another table in other database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an SQL Azure Database Server with 2 databases and I need to insert records from a table of the first database to another table in the other database. Both databases are on the same server with the same security settings/login.

I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO DatabaseB.dbo.TableB (ColumnA, ColumnB)
SELECT TableA.ColumnA, TableA.ColumnB
FROM DatabaseA.dbo.TableA
```

When I run the SQL with SSMS I get:

```
Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Reference to database and/or server name in 'DatabaseB.dbo.TableB ' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-database queries such as the one you're trying to do aren't supported with SQL Database, except for read-only elastic queries. You'd need to execute two separate operations.

Specifics a round T-SQL differences between SQL Server and SQL Database are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information).

Info about elastic queries: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview).

Comment: What do you mean by 'two separate operations' ?

Comment: Meaning, you'd need to first do a query against database A. Then do your insert to database B. Independently. Using separate connection strings / database contexts. As stated, you cannot bridge two databases in a single query (regardless that the credentials are the same).

Comment: First query against database A, store the result temporarily 'somewhere' (?) and then copy the results to the table in database B. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Pretty straightforward. Just two database calls, passing data from one to the other, via your app layer.